# How to call function from the constructor of a JS class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm creating a matrix class (to be used in a react app) which I'd like define this way:

```
class Matrix extends Object {
    constructor(r, c) {
        super();
        this.rows = new Array(r);
        for (var i=0; i<r; i++) {
            this.rows[i] = new Array(c);
        }
        this.assign((v,i,j) => (i===j)? 1:0);   // ERROR HERE
    }
    assign(f) {
        for (var i=0; i<this.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j=0; j<this.rows[i].length; j++) {
                this.rows[i][j] = f(this.rows[i][j], i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    // and so on
```

This compiles okay via webpack, but while running, I get an error in the chrome console saying that **_this.assign is not a function**.

I can make it work this way:

```
constructor(r, c) {
    super();
    this.rows = new Array(r);
    for (var i=0; i<r; i++) {
        this.rows[i] = new Array(c);
    }
    this.assign = function(f) {
        for (var i=0; i<r; i++) {
            for (var j=0; j<r; j++) {
                this.rows[i][j] = f(this.rows[i][j], i, j);
            }
        }
    };
    this.assign((v,i,j) => (i===j)? 1:0);
}
```

But that's wrong, right?  I shouldn't have to define all of an object's functions in the constructor, right?  In the very same file, I define react classes like:

```
class MatrixComponent extends React.Component { ... }
```

and those are able to call functions without defining them in the constructor.  What am I missing?

Comment: I didn't use webpack, but I can't reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/vxpxmaf1/1 though I **did** get an error that `r` is not defined within `assign` (indeed it isn't), so I changed it to `this.rows.length`.

Comment: @apsillers - thanks.  copy/paste error from when I moved the function out of the constructor scope.  I guess your experiment shows me that it's something about webpack compiling this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing `extends Object` and the `super()` call seems to work for me.

```
class Matrix { // extends Object {
    constructor(r, c) {
        // super();
        this.assign();
    }
    assign() {
    }
}
```

Every class has Object in its prototype chain already, so you don't gain anything by extending Object. `extends Object` is implicit, so remove it.

---

It seems that the handling of `extends Object` is a bug in Babel. The Chromium browser's built-in es6 engine handles the code just fine, since it was fixed here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3886

But it looks like Babel's transpiled es5 is broken.

[image: Working es6 in Chrome]

---

To somewhat explain this behavior, let's take a look at the transpiled es5 from babel.

Given this es6:

```
class OtherClass {}

class OtherClassExtender extends OtherClass {
    constructor(r, c) {
        super();
        this.assign();
    }
    assign() {
    }
}

class ObjectExtender extends Object {
    constructor(r, c) {
        super();
        this.assign();
    }
    assign() {
    }
}

new OtherClassExtender(1, 2);
new ObjectExtender(1, 2);
```

We'll take just a snippet of the transpiled es5. I've removed a lot of code. This is not the full transpiled source:

```
function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) {
  if (!self) {
    throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");
  }
  if (call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function")) {
    return call;
  } else {
    return self;
  }
}

var OtherClass = function OtherClass() {};

var OtherClassExtender = function (_OtherClass) {    
    function OtherClassExtender(r, c) {
        var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _OtherClass.call(this));
        _this.assign();
        return _this;
    }
    OtherClassExtender.prototype.assign = function assign() {};
    return OtherClassExtender;
}(OtherClass);

var ObjectExtender = function (_Object) {
    function ObjectExtender(r, c) {
        var _this2 = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _Object.call(this));
        _this2.assign();
        return _this2;
    }
    ObjectExtender.prototype.assign = function assign() {};
    return ObjectExtender;
}(Object);

new OtherClassExtender(1, 2);
new ObjectExtender(1, 2);
```

`_possibleConstructorReturn` is basically `super`, where Babel is keeping a reference of the class' super-class so method calls can properly traverse the inheritance hierarchy. It basically says "The super-class has methods defined, so let's look there for methods (like `assign`)". There's no sense in adding `Object` itself to that hierarchy since any object in Javascript will inherit methods from `Object` anyway.

By stepping through the transpiled code, `_possibleConstructorReturn(OtherClassExtender, OtherClass)` says `typeof call` is `undefined` so it returns `OtherClassExtender`.

`_possibleConstructorReturn(ObjectExtender, Object)` says `typeof call` is `object` so it returns `Object`.

Object *instances* don't have an `assign` method. `assign` is a class method on the `Object` class, it doesn't exist on `(new Object).assign` for example.

Comment: I see that, too.  Thanks.  Still really more looking for an explanation of this I can reason off of in future problems.

Comment: I guess I'm in over my head a little with trans-compiling and babel.  I wonder if this explains why I can't set breakpoints, either.  Thanks very much for this!

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, I discovered that extending `null` vs `Object`, fixes the problem:

```
class Matrix extends null { ... }
```

I guess this is an answer, but I'm mystified about why, and what was wrong with how I was trying to do it.  **I will happily mark correct a better answer** than this one: on that really explains how this stuff works.